# How to pass async data retrieved in splashscreen to App.js?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

[This article](https://whatdidilearn.info/2019/01/13/how-to-implement-a-splash-screen-in-react-native.html) explains how to use splash screen to load data before initial screen. Basically it defines:

```
const InitialNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  Splash: SplashScreen,
  App: AppNavigator
});

export default createAppContainer(InitialNavigator);
```

Here is the `AppNavigator`:

```
const AppNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: HomeNavigator
    },
    HighScores: {
      screen: HighScoresScreen
    },
    {
     initialRouteName: initialScreen,
   } 
  }
);
```

The `initialScreen` will be based on the data loaded during initialization.

Here is component `SplashScreen` which call 2 async functions to load variable `result` and `user`:

```
class SplashScreen extends React.Component {
  performTimeConsumingTask = async() => {
    var result, user;
    try {
    result = await helper.getJwtToken();
    console.log("App.js token result is : ", result);
    if (result) {
      console.log("App.js result is true. Retrieve user");
      user = await helper._getUser(result.password, result.username); 
      console.log("User is : ", user.name);

    } else {
      console.log("App.js result is false");

    };
    console.log("I am out of App.js async without error");
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Error in retrieving token : ", err);
    return "";

  };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    // Preload data from an external API
    // Preload data using AsyncStorage
    const data = await this.performTimeConsumingTask();

    if (data !== null) {
      this.props.navigation.navigate('App');
    }
  }
.......
```

But how can I pass the value of `result` and `user` to `App`?

Comment: Your function `performTimeConsumingTask()` has only one return in `catch(err)`, thus it would return empty string on error or return undefined if no error occurs. In both cases, `data !== null` will be true and navigation will always navigate to `App`. Is it intended?

Comment: My bad. I coped handling portion from the example and intended to show as a placeholder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to save those data in global state (e.g. React Hook or redux), or in storage (e.g. using react-native-async-storage). The next screen will need to access shared resource to retrieve data. Following example uses async storage to store data:

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

performTimeConsumingTask = async() => {
    var result, user;
    try {
    result = await helper.getJwtToken();
    console.log("App.js token result is : ", result);
    if (result) {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('jwtToken', result);
      console.log("App.js result is true. Retrieve user");
      user = await helper._getUser(result.password, result.username); 
      console.log("User is : ", user.name);
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('user', user);
    } else {
      console.log("App.js result is false");

    };
    console.log("I am out of App.js async without error");
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Error in retrieving token : ", err);
    return "";

  };
  }
```

Another solution is passing `result` & `user` as params in method `navigation.navigate`. To do that, your function `performTimeConsumingTask` needs to return both objects.

```
class SplashScreen extends React.Component {
  performTimeConsumingTask = async() => {
    var result, user;
    try {
    result = await helper.getJwtToken();
    console.log("App.js token result is : ", result);
    if (result) {
      console.log("App.js result is true. Retrieve user");
      user = await helper._getUser(result.password, result.username); 
      console.log("User is : ", user.name);
      return {
        user,
        result,
        success: true
      }
    } else {
      throw new Error("App.js result is false");
    };
    throw new Error("I am out of App.js async without error");
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Error in retrieving token : ", err);
    return {
      success: false,
      error: err.message
    };

  };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    // Preload data from an external API
    // Preload data using AsyncStorage
    const data = await this.performTimeConsumingTask();

    if (data !== null && data.success === true) {
      this.props.navigation.navigate('App', data);
    }
  }
```

Comment: `App.js` is not a component class(has no constructor, no componentDidMount and etc), can I still pass params just like for component? This is where I stuck.

Comment: Yes, params will be a part of `props.navigation` in `App`: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#getparam-get-a-specific-param-value-with-a-fallback. Both class component and functional component have access to `props`, so params should be available regardless.

Answer (score 1):

you can pass a parameter named "params" to pass value to the next screen

take a look at the [document](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#navigate-link-to-other-screens)

Answer (score 1):

Try to pass params:

```
class SplashScreen extends React.Component {
  performTimeConsumingTask = async() => {
    var result, user;
    try {
    result = await helper.getJwtToken();
    console.log("App.js token result is : ", result);
    if (result) {
      console.log("App.js result is true. Retrieve user");
      user = await helper._getUser(result.password, result.username); 
      console.log("User is : ", user.name);
      return {result, user};
    } else {
      console.log("App.js result is false");

    };
    console.log("I am out of App.js async without error");
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Error in retrieving token : ", err);
    return {result: null, user: null};

  };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    // Preload data from an external API
    // Preload data using AsyncStorage
    const data = await this.performTimeConsumingTask();

    if (data !== null) {
      this.props.navigation.navigate('App', {result, user});
    }
  }
```

and inside App you can use it in this way:

```
const { result, user } = this.props.navigation.state.params;
```